# Conditional cell rendering in react-table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, react-table

I have a column for buttons to toggle a modal. The problem is, I don't want to display the button for every single row. I only want to display the button on the first entry of the color. 
Note that the colors are unpredictable (you don't know what colors will be displayed beforehand).

For example,

```
color toggler
black    +
red      +
red          //don't display it here
yellow   +
blue     +
blue        //don't display it here
blue        //don't display it here
orange   +
red      +
black    +
black       //don't display it here
blue     +
```

I have try to go through the document and some example, but I can't seem to find a solution to it (maybe something that I missed ?).

What I did was storing the first color in the state. Then I did with the theCheckFunc:

```
let flag = true 
if (nextColor !== this.state.color)
 this.setState({color: nextColor})
 flag = false
return flag
```

Then in the columns I did.

```
Cell: props => (this.theCheckFunc(props) && <div onClick={somefunc}> + <div>)
```

However, everything seems to be frozen. The browser doesn't even respond.
Any good suggestion on how to do this ?

Comment: Are the cells being added one at a time by the user or are they all computed at once and displayed?

Comment: Right now, at once and displayed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use state with this, since you don't want to re-render based on new input. Instead, compute the array as part of the render.

For example, assuming that when you get to your render statement, you have a random array of colors like this:

`['red', 'red', 'black', 'purple', 'purple']`

Then this function could create the array you need with the data for render:

```
function getTableRowData(arr) {
  let tableRowData = []
  arr.forEach((color, n) => {
    let toggler = true
    if (n !== 0 && arr[n - 1] === color) {
      toggler = false
    }
    tableRowData.push({ color, toggler, })
  })
  return tableRowData
}
```

Then you can iterate over the tableRowData in your render return and have it display the way you want to.

Answer (score 0):

First set your color control variables in state or in class wherever you choose. In this example i'm choosing to control them over state.

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);

            this.state = {
                firstRedAlreadyHere: false,
                firstBlueAlreadyHere: false,
                firstGrayAlreadyHere:false,
                ....
                ...
            }
}
```

then open a function to prepare a table. Later Use that function in render() to put table on component.

```
function putValuesToTable()
{

    let table = [];

        for (let i = 0; i < (YOUR_LENGTH); i++) {
            {
                let children = [];   /* SUB CELLS */

                /* IF RED COLOR IS NEVER CAME BEFORE, PUT A BUTTON NEAR IT */
                if(!this.state.firstRedAlreadyHere)
                children.push(<td>
                   <SomeHtmlItem></SomeHtmlItem></td> <td><button </button></td>)
                /* ELSE DON'T PUT BUTTON AND CHANGE STATE. */
                else
                {
                  children.push(<SomeHtmlItem></SomeHtmlItem>);
                  this.state.firstRedAlreadyHere = true;
                }
                table.push(<tr>{children}</tr>);
            }
        }
return table;
}
```

I am changing state directly instead of `this.setState()`; because I don't want to trigger a refresh :). In render function, call putValuesToTable like this

```
render()
{
return (<div>
<table>
         <tbody>
         <tr>
         <th>SomeParameter</th>
         <th>SomeParameter2</th>         
         </tr>
             {this.putValuesToTable}
         </tbody>
         </table>
</div>);
}
```

Use this example to extend your code according to your aim.

Comment: Im using tannerlinsley/react-table.
Perhaps I should edit my question in which the colors are unpredictable - randomly (you don't know what colors will be display). Hence it could be, purple, purple, blue, blue , in which u don't know the purple color exists beforehand

Comment: Open an array. When a random color generated, push it to array by it's name and each time you generate a random color again, check whole array if its contains same color somewhere in it, do not display the button.